# How to Edit Bootstrap Tokenfield Tag Data using PHP Ajax?

Tags: php, css, ajax, tags

I am Inserting tags using  Bootstrap Tokenfield Tag Data. It works fine with insert operation. But I can not able to update that tags data. How to update tag in database. I am listing all tags that from database. But How to update I can not get idea, how to edit tags value.
Please help.

MY php code look like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-label" for="validation-username">Tags <span class="text text-danger">*</span></label>
            <?php 

                $tags = explode(",",$a['tags']);

                foreach($tags as $t => $value){?> 
                    <span class="tm-tag tm-tag-info" id="CIGpD_<?php echo $t;?>">

                        <span><?php echo $value;?></span>

                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tm-tag-remove" id="CIGpD_Remover_<?php echo $t;?>" tagidtoremove="<?php echo $t;?>">x</a>

                    </span>
            <?php }  ?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $a['tags']?>" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="typeahead tm-input form-control tm-input-info"/>
</div>
```

My JS look like this

```
$('.tm-tag-remove').click(function(){
            var tagid = document.querySelector('.tm-tag-info').id;
            $('#' + tagid).remove();

            var tag = $('.tm-input-info').val();
            console.log(tag);
            var tagArr = tag.split(',');

            tagArr.forEach(function(tagArr, value){

                var spanid = $('#CIGpD_' + value).text();
                // console.log(spanid);
            });



        });
```

Comment: can u post the code?

Comment: Yes, sure. @DevsiOdedra

Comment: Hi !! @DevsiOdedra I have update code in question.

Comment: You can update it through javascript

Comment: @Omi Can you please guide me to do so. Because I have no idea, How it be happen with `javascript` ?

Comment: Hi !! @DevsiOdedra Can you please help me. It would be great help for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning  values from php you should assign value from javascript so that it will update tags. `$a['tags']` you need this array in javascript like I have used in example `yourTags` or you can try comma speared values instead also.

Here is the working example:

```js
$('.tm-tag-remove').click(function() {
  var tagid = document.querySelector('.tm-tag-info').id;
  $('#' + tagid).remove();

  var tag = $('.tm-input-info').val();
  console.log(tag);
  var tagArr = tag.split(',');

  tagArr.forEach(function(tagArr, value) {

    var spanid = $('#CIGpD_' + value).text();
    // console.log(spanid);
  });
});

var yourTags = ['blue','red','white'];

$('.typeahead').tokenfield({})
$('.typeahead').tokenfield('setTokens', yourTags.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/tokenfield-typeahead.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label" for="validation-username">Tags <span class="text text-danger">*</span></label>


  <input type="text" value="" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="typeahead tm-input form-control tm-input-info" />
</div>
```